# Getting ints array instead of characters array

Tags: java

I am trying a code problem to convert double to string and then insert that to an array. I tried various methods but these don't give expected output.

```
public int[] makePi() {
  double PI = Math.PI;

  String sPI = String.valueOf(PI);
  int[] Arr = new int[3];

  for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
  {
    Arr[i] = sPI.charAt(i);
  }

  return Arr; 
}
```

Output should be an array with first three characters of PI as below :-

`[ 3, 1, 4 ]`   while I am getting `[51, 46, 49]`

I will handle decimal character if needed.

Just a hint is needed.

Please don't provide full program that will be a spoiler. :-)

Comment: What does your method output?

Comment: u need string array or int array?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava any will do..

Comment: [`Character.isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) and [`Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) will help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table. Do you see what are the corresponding chars for the integers you're getting? This should be a good hint for you.

Note that you're assigning the result to an `int` array, while you're running on *characters*.

Comment: I think this question(stupidity) doesn't meet the standard of SO.

Comment: @RanchiRhino I hope there's no spoiler.

Comment: @RanchiRhino It does. You described your problem and provided a reproducible code.

Comment: Not ASCII, [Unicode/UTF-16](http://unicode-table.com/en/) (numbers are hexadecimal and are in rows of 16.) From the question, 51 would be 0x33, which in UTF-16 is the single UTF-16 code unit needed for the Unicode codepoint [U+0033](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0033/index.htm). [I think it's better to learn that you know a little about Unicode than to think you need to know ASCII and that it is all you need to know.]

Comment: @TomBlodget I'm actually very familiar with unicode/UTF-16. I even wrote a [blogpost](http://marounbassam.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/must-know-unicode-and-character-sets.html) a while ago.

Comment: I was suggesting that you don't start people off on the wrong foot by teaching them ASCII. Java, JavaScript, .NET, HTML, … all use Unicode. As you say, it is a "must know."

Comment: @TomBlodget What I said wrong? The table I liked to is called the ASCII table, nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

you're storing chars into an int array. hence theie respective ascii values will be stored in array (you're effectively converting char to int)

3 (char) -> 51 (ASCII Value)

. (char) -> 46 (ASCII Value)

1 (char) -> 49 (ASCII Value)

your array length is 3, so only first 3 chars are converted to ascii which is 3.1, not 3.14

But now if you want to store it into an char array (which i feel you're trying to do), all you need is  -

```
char[] charArray = sPI.toCharArray();
```

Plus, I dont think you want to store in int array as though you can convert ascii values int their respective int value, but what about '.' which is not a valid int.

Answer (score 1):

What you get in your array are values of characters (so something like 70 for '3', I neither remember nor want to remember exact values). You must convert value of character into the number itself. Hint: characters are numbered in the following way:

'0' - n

'1' - n + 1

'2' - n + 2

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the numeric values of the digits, I would advise against doing explicit comparisons and arithmetic on the character values.

The [`Character` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) provides helper methods, which are less error-prone and more readable:

```
int outIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3 /* && i < sPI.length() */; ++i) {
  char c = sPI.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    Arr[outIndex++] = Character.getNumericValue(c);
  }
}
/* assert outIndex == 3 */
return Arr;
```

I've commented out some code which I'd put in there for more robustness - it's not strictly necessary in this case, since we know that `sPI` has at least 3 digits in it. (Mind you, if we're going to hard-code that assumption, we may as well simply `return new int[] { 3, 1, 4 };`).

Comment: In that case (hard-coding), I should round the double to two decimal places.